# How does composing with id change type

Tags: haskell, function-composition

If the type of `foldr` is

```
> :t foldr
forall a b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

and

```
> :t id
forall a. a -> a
```

then I would expect `foldr (.) id` to have the same type as `foldr`, rather than

```
> :t foldr (.) id
forall b. [b -> b] -> b -> b
```

It appears I'm mistaken about how composition works, because I had thought that for a function `f` that `f . id` would give `f(id(x)) == f(x)`, preserving the type of `f`. What am I misunderstanding that would clarify the meaning of `foldr (.) id` and composition more generally?

Comment: `id` is not relevant here. `(.)` is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is *not* composition with `id`, as you'd get from `foldr . id` (notice the absence of parens). That would indeed be equivalent to `foldr` alone, perhaps the most important equivalency in category theory and thus also fundamental to Haskell.

Instead, what you've done there is, passed both `(.)` and `id` as *arguments* to `foldr`: putting `.` in parens makes it just another expression so ordinary Haskell function parsing applies, i.e. greedily use consecutive terms as arguments to the first one. You're lucky that this makes for a good type at all, for instance `succ (.) id` would have given the ridiculous signature `Enum ((c -> c) -> (a -> c) -> a -> c) => (a -> c) -> a -> c`.

How exactly it works with `foldr` can be seen by writing

```
 (.) :: (y->z) -> (x->y) -> (x->z)
```

unify `(x->y) = (x->z)` as in `foldr`'s argument, i.e. `y = z`,

```
 (.) :: (y->y) -> (x->y) -> (x->y)

 foldr (.) :: (x->y) -> [y->y] -> (x->y)
```

Then `id` also requires `x = y`,

```
 foldr (.) id :: [x->x] -> (x->x)
```

Comment: Where you say "unify `(x->y) = (x->z)` as in `foldr`'s argument", which part of `foldr`'s type signature do you get this from? I'm having a hard time seeing how to match the single argument functions in `(.)`'s signature (that is, `(y->z)` and `(x->y)`) into the double argument function of `foldr`'s first argument (`(a->b->b)`).

Comment: Oh, I think I see. `foldr`'s first arg `(a->b->b)` corresponds to the whole type of of `(.) :: (y->z) -> (x->y) -> (x->z)`, so `a=(y->z), b=(x->y)=(x->z)`. Nevermind...I guess that's what you already said.

Answer (score 6):

You are not composing `foldr` with `id`. That would be `foldr . id`. What you are actually doing is *applying* `foldr` to `(.)`, and then applying the result of such application to `id`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying here is that you are going to be composing a list of functions who all have the same type (since they are in a list). `id` is the initial function that you'll be folding from. When you are done composing all of them, you'll get back a function. It might be easier to see the result type as `[b -> b] -> (b -> b)`.

By the way, when you use an operator in Haskell and you want to infix it, you omit the parantheses. Only when you are using it as any other function do you include the parantheses.